# Configuration Error - Unrecognized attribute 'name' / Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

When trying to access my database in a live web application I get the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'name'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Source File: C:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config    Line: 115

My web config where line 115 is located:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" /> // Line: 115
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /></DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

When I remove: `name="MySQL Data Provider"` from that line, I just get another error and go around in circles.

Also when I refresh the page and remove that `name` part I get:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can login to database with your `roomauditsystem`  and `omitted` manyally?

Comment: Why do you have two entries for `add name=...`?

Comment: @GertArnold I don't know, I thought I knew what I was doing but I've gone round in so many circles I've confused myself. After installing different packages I think I ended up with an older version so I believe I can deleted the first 'add name=...'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 8 hours I managed to solve this. For some reason, in NuGet Package Manager it said the version I had installed was Version=6.9.9.0 so I added:

```
<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
```

to my web.config and yet it still didn't work, I tried everything, reinstalling, etc. etc. and then eventually I went into my bin folder and the actual version there was 6.8.3.0 yet NuGet displayed 6.9.9.0 - strange!

I deleted these from the bin folder and then reinstalled the latest version and it all worked!

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and nothing was working for me. I fixed it by changing the .NET framework version to 4.5 instead of 4.5.2.Take a look at this [article.](http://blog.brendanlacanette.com/2015/07/systemcomponentmodelwin32exception.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input but I'm still getting the same error!

Comment: After taking a look on your `Exception Stack Trace` i think some how your application is not able to access the database on server.Please check twice your connection string everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I think the name must not contains spaces and also you have two data providers with same name so your code should be like this:

```
<add name="MySQLDataProvider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  <add name="MySQLDataProvider2" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /></DbProviderFactories>
```