# Type is not resolved for member 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0,

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

I use EntityFramework(v.6.0.0.0) code first. .Net framework 4.6.01586. MySQL connector Version=6.9.9.0. MySQL server version = '5.5.28'
.When I try to "update-database" i get this error "**Type is not resolved for member 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.**".
It is regular migration. Just "CreateTable". I tried to generate script and apply it to the database manually (via MySql Workbench)and it works. If I use Sql("my sql script") via migration it does not work too.

Comment: You are targeting (or are using .DLLs that targets) some .NET framework version "x", but the version installed in your computer is "y". Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162456/configuration-error-unrecognized-attribute-name-unable-to-find-the-request

Comment: Please make sure your connection string is correct (I had a similar issue myself)

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed MySQL Connector ? I have downloaded mysql-connector-net-6.9.9.msi and it solved my problem. Download link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=463758